# How can I access a variable inside another function?

Tags: php, variables, global

I have two functions that print some values. I need to use the variable $mv in the second function. However, $mv can only be defined in the first function. I have tried all types of PHP global examples and none of them has allowed the $mv variable to be used or visible or accessible in the second function.

```
 function printMobilePrev(&$mobileprevresults) {
       if (count($mobileprevresults->getRows()) > 0) {




    $mv = $mobileprevRows[0][0];

    $mobileprevRows = $mobileprevresults->getRows();

    echo '<p>Previous period (sessions): '.$mobileprevRows[0][0].'..............................';


  } else {
    print '<p>No results found.</p>';
  }

}


function printMobileCurr(&$mobilecurrresults) {
   if (count($mobilecurrresults->getRows()) > 0) {



    $mobdiff = ($mobcur - $mv);

    $mobpctchg = ($mobdiff / $mobprev) * 100;

    $mobilecurrRows = $mobilecurrresults->getRows();


     echo '<p>Previous period (sessions): '.$mobileprevRows[0][0].'..............................';
     echo '<p>Previous period (sessions): '.$mv.'..............................';
     echo '<p>Current period (sessions): '.$mobilecurrRows[0][0].'..............................';

    if ($mobdiff > 0){

        echo '<p>Percent increase: '.$mobpctchg.'..............................';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Percent decrease: '.$mobpctchg.'..............................';
    }      

  } else {
    print '<p>No results found.</p>';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[global scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**:

That is what you want to do:

```
$mv = 0;

function function1()
{
    global $mv;
    $mv = 'whatever';
    //code
}

function function2()
{
    global $mv;
    // use $mv;
}
```

Comment: the first `global $mv;` does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You have to predefine that variable OUTSIDE any function, and then you can use Global to get that to any function.

Comment: It doesn't need to be defined outside. It just needs to have the `global` keyword inside the functions that use it, even if it's initialized there. Or better `$GLOBALS['mv']` or better still return it from the first and pass to the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it by reference. For example

```
function doSomething(&$mv) {
   $mv = 1;
}

function doSomethingElse($mv) {
   return $mv;
}

$mv = 0;
doSomething($mv);
echo doSomethingElse($mv); //Output: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return $mv after your print and save that in a var to pass to the next function:

```
$printMobilePrev = printMobilePrev();

function printMobilePrev(&$mobileprevresults) {

   $mv = $mobileprevRows[0][0];

   ...
    print '<p>No results found.</p>';
    return $mv;
   ...

}

$printMobileCurr = printMobileCurr(&$mobilecurrresults,$mv);

function printMobileCurr(&$mobilecurrresults,$mv) {
     ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to make a correct use of globals.

declare your $mv variable as global before asigning it a value on your first function

```
global $mv;
$mv = $mobileprevRows[0][0];
```

use global at the begining on your second function before using it

```
function printMobileCurr(&$mobilecurrresults) {
if (count($mobilecurrresults->getRows()) > 0) {
global $mv;
```